# Select all data from the last 5 days

Tags: sql, mysql

In mysql I need to obtain all the last 5 days records.
So if I have

```
Name       date
aaaa      20/11/2010
dddd*      24/11/2010*
bbbb      22/11/2010
cccc      23/11/2010
eeee*     25/11/2010*
ffff*      26/11/2010*
```

I need only the last 5 days records.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT name,date 
from Lineas
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

but it isn´t working....

Comment: What format is the date field in? Why doesn't your query work? What happens?

Comment: it´s datetime. The problem is that the data I obteined it´s also with records from "the future" like 2011/01/22

Comment: That's what your query wants, no? It asks for everything newer than three days ago. Change it to 'between today and three days ago' eliminate future dates. Just add `AND DATE <= CURDATE()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the problem is "records from the future" then you simply need to restrain your results a bit more than you've already done:

```
SELECT name,date 
from Lineas
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND date <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried between

```
SELECT  name,
        date  
from    Lineas 
WHERE   date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY date DESC
```